# Возврат результата в виде строки таблицы

Tags: postgresql, функции, table, plpgsql

### Всем привет!

Есть таблица **doc1**. Приложение передаёт в функцию строку из таблицы
    select * from rule_calc1(('(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001,"1,00","5,00","0,00")')::doc1); 
Далее функция выбирает значения из этой строки, исходя из структуры и названия колонок, потом считает нужные значения и должна вернуть ту же строку, только уже с пересчитанными значениями в таком же виде, как и получила и уже через приложение запускает update строки.
Вопрос в том, как написать **RETURNS** для этой функции.
Код для создания таблицы, функцию и вызов функции прилагаю.
  **Спасибо**

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."doc1" (
"id" uuid DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid NOT NULL,
"price1" money DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"price2" money DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
"price3" money DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL

)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;

INSERT INTO "public"."doc1" VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002', '10,00 ?', '3,00 ?', '0,00 ?');
INSERT INTO "public"."doc1" VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001', '1,00 ?', '5,00 ?', '0,00 ?');


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rule_calc1(info doc1)
returns SETOF  info2 doc1
AS
$BODY$
declare 
id uuid; 
price1 money; 
price2 money; 
price3 money;
begin
price1 := info.price1; 
price2 := info.price2; 
price3 := info.price3; 

if price3 = 0 then price3 := price1 + price2 ;
end if;
info2.price1 := price1; 
info2.price2 := price2; 
info2.price3 := price3; 
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select * from rule_calc1(('(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001,"1,00","5,00","0,00")')::dociteminfo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`returns SETOF` указывает только какого типа будет результат. Какими переменными вы этот результат поименуете в функции - дело ваше.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rule_calc1(info doc1)
returns SETOF doc1
AS
$BODY$
declare result doc1;
begin
   select d.* into result from "public"."doc1" as d where d.id = info.id;
   if not found then
      return;
   end if;

   result.price1 := result.price1 * 10;

   return next result;
end
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но как получить значение result.price1, если нужно значение, от которого нужно производить расчеты, находятся во входном параметре, а не в бд, где, например, на начало 0?

Comment: `result := info;`? `result.price1 := info.price1 * 10;` Или о чём вы вообще?

Comment: Да, именно об этом. Я когда уже написал, понял, что ступил) Спасибо!